# Magento 2 Custom Table Auto Increament Column value disorder

Tags: magento2, database, auto-increment

In my custom module, I have a database table with auto increment col. The columns values initially work fine but when I delete any record the value increased like this order
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,110,115,220,10004,1567899 etc (example).

if anyone knows what can be the issue will be appreciated.

table schema screenshot:
[image]

Inserted Records:
[image]